# Eclipse does not see my Toshiba Folio 100 Android 2.2 tablet

Tags: android, eclipse, deployment

After a) growing tired of the slowness of the emulator and b) nearing the end of the development of my first android app, I decided to connect my old and forgotten Toshiba Folio 100 android 2.2 tablet to my Windows 7 development PC, in order to deploy my android app. The PC and tablet 'see' each other, that is, the PC sees the tablet as a disk drive. In the android settings I switched on the developer mode. I read through the many advice threads of this site concerning deploying the app to a real device. To start with, in windows explorer, computer, right click, manage, does not result in recognition of the tablet, except for Toshiba storage USB device.

In Eclipse I went to Run configurations, target tab,tried all the different radio buttons settings, to no avail. The devices view, same story. Eclipse does not see the tablet. I also tried some old Archos 48 mini tablet, again nothing.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you see it as an android device? open a command prompt and type "adb devices" make sure your tablet is listed there, otherwise you need to find some adb drivers for it, you may want to try the generic adb usb driver.

Comment: result: "emulator-5554 device", so he does not see it.

Comment: try to open device manager, check if your tablet is displayed there with an yellow mark

Comment: In the Android SDK manager I installed almost everything there is to install, like google usb driver. So where do I get the 'generic adb usb driver'?

Comment: As I said, the device manager merely sees the tablet as a diskdrive, without exclamation marks. Driver is said to function properly.

Comment: that's the google usb driver that you are mentioning, still - it does not guarantee that it will work for your device. try to use that driver.

Comment: How do I link the google usb driver, listed in the SDK manager, to the toshiba tablet?

Comment: The fact that you see the device as a disk-drive does not help you, you need to see it as an "android" device; Android Debug Bridge is the one that has to "see" your device in order for you to deploy apps from Eclipse.

Comment: From device manager try to "update driver" for your device and point to the google usb driver.

Comment: I have the choice between google androidwinusb86 and androidwinusba64. I have a windows 64 bit machine... so the second?

Comment: yes, try the second one - keep in mind, it's not guaranteed that the driver may work with your device; it's a long shot if you don't have any other driver specific for your device.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26960/discussion-between-jhulst-and-marius-m)

Comment: I do not have it working yet, but I believe that the link provided by Marius in the chat is probably the way to go forward. http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/enable-adb-usb-drivers-for-nvidia-tegra-based-android-tablets/

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing the device in explorer listed as a disk drive it probably means you have the wrong USB mode on the device.  It's called different things on different devices, but on many devices it's referred to as "Charge Only" mode (or not mass storage mode).  Also make sure USB debugging is enabled on the device.

Comment: USB debugging is enabled... Not sure about 'charge only'... just option 'switch on USB storage' + OK/Cancel

Comment: OK.. so just make sure USB storage is NOT enabled.